# Is there a way in T-SQL / SSMS to round interest rate values to the nearest eighth (0.125)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to round interest rates to the nearest eighth (0.125) in T-SQL.

I have found things like the following which will round to the nearest quarter or half, but nothing to the nearest eighth.

```sql
round(indexrate/25,2) * 25
```

Does anyone have any experience/solutions that they can share?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: The idea is identical to what you have, just use an Eighth (0.125) instead of a quarter (0.25)...

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT ROUND(indexrate * 8.0, 0) / 8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ROUND(indexrate/-.125) FROM ....